# Scala Type System Help: Let a failure cascade up the stack

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-systems

I've been wrestling with this beast for a few days and need some guidance. My original code is too large and cumbersome so I've tried to create all the pieces here and it (almost) compiles, i'm getting some errors with my made up code below.

What i'm trying to do is let a "Failure" cascade up the chain to my API layer. The domain is around connecting to a backend to get a list of equipment health checks by MAC address. An account has multiple equipments, and an equipment has multiple mac addresses. Only the primary macs will get a successful response from the backend system.

> Update 1: By Failure here I mean connection issues to the backend client. an Unknown mac (i.e. a mac that's not found/resolved) is not considered a failure. It should be reported as a Success.

Here's what I've recreated thus far for your pleasure to emulate my system. Line 18 and 19 can be toggled to see different conditions.

```
    import scala.util._

    trait EquipmentStatus { val mac: String }
    case class Offline(mac: String) extends EquipmentStatus
    case class Online(mac: String) extends EquipmentStatus
    case class Unknown(mac: String) extends EquipmentStatus

    case class EquipmentHealth(mac: String, status: EquipmentStatus)

    case class Account(number: Int, equipments: List[Equipment])
    case class Equipment(macs: List[String]) { 
        def primaryMacs = macs.filter(_.endsWith("00")) 
    }

    object StatusChecker { 
        def checkBatchStatuses(macs: List[String]): 
        Try[List[EquipmentStatus]] = 
            //Success(macs.map(Online(_))) 
            Failure(new Exception("Connection Timed Out"))
    }


    object DeviceService {

        def getMacsByAccount(macs: List[String], equipments: List[Equipment]): Try[List[EquipmentHealth]] = {

            for {
                mac <- macs 
                equipment <- equipments.filter(_.macs.contains(mac))
                statuses <- StatusChecker.checkBatchStatuses(equipment.primaryMacs)
            } yield resolveStatus(statuses, mac)// ######### HOW DO I CONVERT/COLLECT Try[EquipmentHealth] to Try[List[EquipmentHealth]] AND ALSO ALLOW Try[Exception()] TO PROPAGATE UP AS WELL? 

        }

        def resolveStatus(statuses: List[EquipmentStatus], mac: String): Try[EquipmentHealth] = {

            statuses.partition(_.mac == mac) match {
                case (Nil, Nil) => Success(EquipmentHealth(mac, Unknown(mac)))
                case (List(one), Nil) => Success(EquipmentHealth(mac, one))
                case _ => Success(EquipmentHealth(mac, Unknown(mac)))
            }
        }
    }


    val equipments = List(Equipment(List("mac100", "mac222")), Equipment(List("mac333", "mac400")))
    val exampleAcc = Account(1234, equipments)

    DeviceService.getMacsByAccount(List("mac222"), exampleAcc.equipments)
```

In my code base, Try is actually a custom Boxed (Either) type that contains Succeeds and Fails. My for comprehension skills are lacking. What I'd like is to go from Try[EquipmentHealth] to Try[List[EquipmentHealth]].

Am I making this too complicated? is there an easier way that I'm not seeing?

Comment: What behaviour do you want if more than one `Try` is `Failure`? Do you want to keep all the error information or just the first error?

Comment: It's not really clear what the desired behaviour is. Since you don't store anything about failures, there's no way to know if the absence of a `Success` with the desired MAC address should be resolved to `Success(EquipmentHealth(mac, Unknown(mac)))` or a `Failure`

Comment: @Dici , Unknown Mac should go up as a Success, Any other failures (e.g. parsing the response from backend, i.e. invalid json), or connection issues, I want those failures to go up and report to the API layer (which is then monitored and we know when failures occur in my system). In other places in my system this happens because I"m usually extracting one-object, not a list, but for some reason I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just want to have `List[Try[EquipmentStatus]]` rather than `Try[List[EquipmentStatus]]` ? The former doesn't allow recovering from individual failures. A comprehension always yields an iterable-like result, you can't return a `Try[List[Something]]` from it.

In order to give a more detailed answer, I'd need you to clarify the expected behaviour. It's quite strange that your `DeviceService.resolveStatus` can only result in a success, and that's mainly because you do not keep any information about which queries failed, so you're unable to decide between *"this lookup has failed"* and *"this MAC address is unknown"*. I think the *unknown* case should be removed and we always assume that if no success was returned, then it was a failure. Otherwise, you need to store a bit more information, like for example `List[(String, Try[EquipmentStatus]]` where the first element of the tuple is the MAC address that was queried (or, for better performance, using a map which keys are the addresses).

Comment: Note: I'm in an airport right now, I'll try to detail my answer a bit soon.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It's not, see my comment above. I'm working on it, just had to go to my gate.

Comment: Please don't post your "work in progress". Wait until you actually have an answer and then post it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, none-the-less @Dici. You're on the right track. I don't want to consider an unfound Mac as a failure, an Unfound/Unknown mac status goes up as a success. Any other failure related to *making* the call, such as tcp connection issues, should go up as Failures. In my system, i use a different Monad that is called a Response[Succeeds, Fails) and works like Either[A,B].

Comment: Then perhaps you need to return tuples as I suggested, so that you know which address the failures corresponded to. I mentioned a list of tuples to avoid changing your code structure too much, but really what would be optimal is a map because it has a lot faster access to a given key. Anything missing from the answer that I could improve on?

Answer (score 1):

The current signature of `getMacsByAccount` is

```
def getMacsByAccount(macs: List[String], ...): Try[List[EquipmentHealth]]
```

This allows a single `Success`/`Failure` result and you cannot check each `mac` independently. If you want to track the error status of each `mac` then you need to return `List[Try[EquipmentHealth]]` rather than `Try[List[EquipmentHealth]]`:

```
def getMacsByAccount(macs: List[String], ...): List[Try[EquipmentHealth]]
```

Implementing this requires a simple change to `getMacsByAccount`:

```
def getMacsByAccount(macs: List[String], equipments: List[Equipment]): List[Try[EquipmentHealth]] =
  for {
    mac <- macs
    equipment <- equipments.filter(_.macs.contains(mac))
    statuses = StatusChecker.checkBatchStatuses(equipment.primaryMacs)
  } yield
    statuses.flatMap(resolveStatus(_, mac))
```

**Note:** At the moment `resolveStatus` always returns `Success` in which case it might as well just return `EquipmentHealth`. If you change this, change the `flatMap` above to `map`.

#### Edit after comments

If you just need a single failure or success, then wrap the whole thing in a `Try` and unpack the inner `Try` values using `get`:

```
def getMacsByAccount(macs: List[String], equipments: List[Equipment]): Try[List[EquipmentHealth]] =
  Try {
    for {
      mac <- macs
      equipment <- equipments.filter(_.macs.contains(mac))
      statuses = StatusChecker.checkBatchStatuses(equipment.primaryMacs).get
    } yield resolveStatus(statuses, mac).get
  }
```

If any of the `Try` values is `Failure` then `get` will throw an exception which is caught by the outer `Try`.

Of course it would be simpler if `checkBatchStatuses` and `resolveStatus` just threw an exception on failure rather than returning `Try`.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I'm going to try to see if I can incorporate this back into my real models and see if it works out.

Comment: Unfotunately this doesn't work. I need to return a list as my success, and failure as failure. I do not need to maintain failures for each. If it's found its status is saved, otherwise it's saved as unknown which is a success scenario still. Only failure states should be when something goes wrong and I can't get a list back.

Comment: @dlite922 OK, I have added the code that keeps the original signature and just returns a single `Success`/`Failure` value.